# Accidentally ran `rm -rf /home`

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery, home, delete

Note that the command I accidentally ran was to recursively delete the root home directory, not the user one. Also not I do not have sudo nor root privileges.

This is not a question about data recovery in the usual sense. For some reason most of the subdirectories of the root `/home` dir seem intact. In particular my user's home directory at `/home/user` still exists and has most/(all?) its subdirectories. `.ssh` is there and a directory called `code` which has all my work files seems to have survived.
However my `.bashrc` file is gone.

`rm -rf /home`

My first question is why did these directories not succumb to the command?

The main purpose of this post is to find out what I *did* delete and steps to get my installation to behave normally again.

On ubuntu the `l=ls` alias isn't available any more so I guess I removed some file containing these.

Certain programs are also missing.

Also tab completion doesn't work. Any ideas how I can get this back?

Comment: don't you have an alias rm='rm -i' ? Just type alias as user you launch the command with.

Comment: Neat, I'll set this up for next time.

Comment: Did you get any errors from it? Did you stop it with e.g. Ctrl-C at some point? Usually, you would have permission to delete your own files, unless you manually remove write access from yourself from a directory (`rm` usually can't deal with that, you need to manually add the permissions back to be able to remove such a directory). Anyway, since you don't have the original set of files any more, it may be a bit difficult to determine what exactly happened.

Comment: @admstg, please don't recommend aliasing `rm`.  That just causes people to be complacent about powerful commands rather than checking them, and can cause people to come spectacularly unstuck in environments without the alias.

Comment: What is the underlying filesystem ? Would fsck actually report any problem ?

Comment: Default versions of things like .bashrc can be found in /etc/skel and you can copy those to your home.

Comment: Yes I think I did see a bunch of warnings in terminal about stuff I couldn't delete(!) and then must have pressed CTRL-C, saving the majority of stuff in my user's home dir which I of course did have permission to delete. Luckily that must have been relatively low down in the order/tree traversal and gave me a chance to come to my senses and see something was amiss. It did delete Documents, .bashrc, most of the contents of Pictures but - thankfully - not the contents of my work directory which I hadn't pushed for a day or so.

Comment: Aliasing `rm` to `rm -i` would have been entirely useless in this case, the `-f` overrides the `-i`.

Comment: @admstg: If you're going to alias `rm` to anything, the more useful one is `rm -I` which prompts for directories or prompts once if there are more than 3 args on the command line, e.g. if a glob matched a lot of stuff.  Unless you specify `-f` like the OP did.  `rm -i` just builds a habit of expecting to have to type `y` all the type so you don't think about it as much.  (Aliasing `mv` and `cp` to `-i` make sense to me, though, my normal use cases for them don't involve overwriting a destination.)

Comment: I once made a similar mistake, and ever since I've aliased `rm` to `rm -v` on my systems, which prints every filename it removes. If I accidentally rm too much, I'll realize and ctrl-C quicker because of the output, _and_ I can inspect what was removed on accident which makes recovery easier.

Comment: I'm not sure why `rm -I` chooses to prompt if > 3 files are to be removed.  My own version of this prompts if there is > 1 file to be removed.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, you should really not ask several questions at the same time. I will answer why your `/home/user` directory was not deleted itself.

You need to understand file permissions on unix-like systems. They are composed of 3 triplets: rwxrwxrwx, the first triplet is the permission of the owner, the second triplet is for the owner group, and the final one is for everybody else (others).

Go into `/home/` and execute `ls -la`, you should see something like:

```
drwxr-xr-x  6 root root  4096 Feb 15  2022 .
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root  4096 Jan 19 20:56 ..
drwxr-xr-x 88 user user  4096 Feb  1 21:22 user
```

Let's take that apart. The `.` directory is the one we are in (`/home/`) you can note that it is owned by user `root` and group `root`. This is not your user, you can "become" that by running `su` or `sudo`, but when you normally execute any command that tries to alter that directory you will be "other", and that is the third triplet. Others have permission `r-x`, meaning that you can read the contents of the directory (listing files and subdirectories) and execute it (change into it and run commands with that directory being current).

When you remove the file or a subdirectory, you are actually not altering that file, you are altering the directory that file is located in. On some systems if you attempt to remove the file that you do not have write ownership of, but you have write on the directory where the file resides you will get a warning, but technically you are allowed to do so.

Let's consider:

```
/         root  root drwxr-xr-x
/test/    user  user drwxrwxr--
/test/t   root  root -rwx------
/tst      user  user -rw-rw-rw-
```

You will be unable without becoming a super-user (root) read or write to the file `/test/t`, however, you will be able to delete that file, because you have write permission on `/test/`.

But the file `/tst` is the opposite. You will have no problem writing to the file, reading its contents, truncating it, etc... But you will not be able to rename or delete that file, because that would require write permission to `/`.

Now, let's go back to your `/home/`, remember that you have had no write permission to `/home` itself, you can do anything *within* `/home/user/`, but you cannot delete it. Therefore all the files inside of it were deleted, but the directory itself has survived.

Answer (score 4):

- better than doing `rm -rf /`
- what I will say and this is coming from a *kill -9* guy who always logs in as *root* this is why you did not delete everything under home as you were logged in as you and not as *root*.

  - you did not explicitly say you were logged in as root, so I assume you were logged in as you so everything else under `/home` should be fine and only what you had write permission on (i.e your home account) would have started actually deleting... up until you `control-C`'d it to interrupt it.
- > what steps to get my installation to behave normally again

  - recreate your user account...

    - `adduser serguio --uid # --gid 100 --no-user-group --create-home --comment Sergio\ Gliesh`
    - adjust the arguments to `adduser` to suit your needs, this is just an example.
    - you'll need to use a different account name than what you previously had, then you can copy what data files & folders from `/home/oldaccount` to `/home/newaccount` but don't copy any of the hidden dot files, that will get things functional.  After that then go through dot files like `.bashrc` if you had specific stuff and cleanly edit that content into the new `/home/<newaccount>/.bashrc`

Comment: \* **worse than** doing `rm -rf /`, because GNU `rm` (the one on Ubuntu) will refuse to act on `/`

Comment: _"better than doing rm -rf /"_ - System files are easily replaced by reinstalling. User files may not be so easily replaced. So I disagree.

Comment: `rm -rf /` should be *at worst* as bad as `rm -rf /home`, because ordinary users shouldn't have write permissions on anything they don't own.

Comment: ... like I said I log in as root all the time

Comment: @ron next time use `sudo` instead. Afaik logging in as root is considered bad practice.